# Session.get in hibernate working while step by step debugging but not while running in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate

I am new to hibernate. I have persisted my data using Hibernate in MySQL. here is my Entity class.

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class SecuredCustomer implements Serializable{

    @Id
    private String loginId;
    private String password;

    @Embedded
    UserInfo userInformation = new UserInfo();

    int allocatedRestaurantTableId;

    @Embedded
    Order order;

    @Embedded
    Bill bill;


    public SecuredCustomer(){
        allocatedRestaurantTableId = -1;
        order = null;
        bill = null;
    }

    public Bill getBill() {
        return bill;
    }


    public void setBill(Bill bill) {
        this.bill = bill;
    }


    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }


    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
    }


    public int getAllocatedRestaurantTableId() {
        return allocatedRestaurantTableId;
    }


    public void setAllocatedRestaurantTableId(int allocatedRestaurantTableId) {
        this.allocatedRestaurantTableId = allocatedRestaurantTableId;
    }

    public UserInfo getUserInformation() {
        return userInformation;
    }

    public void setUserInformation(UserInfo userInformation) {
        this.getUserInformation().setAddress(userInformation.getAddress());
        this.getUserInformation().setAge(userInformation.getAge());
        this.getUserInformation().setName(userInformation.getName());
        this.getUserInformation().setPhoneNumber(userInformation.getPhoneNumber());

    }

    public String getLoginId() {
        return loginId;
    }

    public void setLoginId(String loginId) {
        this.loginId = loginId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
         return this == obj;
    }
}
```

I have persisted this class while the user signs up with a login Id and a password.

Now i am trying to retrieve the data like the following:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
                //Retrieving Data
                Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                session.beginTransaction();
                SecuredCustomer customerInDB = session.get(SecuredCustomer.class, userLoginId);
```

the SQL that the Hibernate creates is as follows:
Hibernate: select securedcus0_.loginId as loginId1_11_0_, securedcus0_.allocatedRestaurantTableId as allocate2_11_0_, securedcus0_.total as total3_11_0_, securedcus0_.password as password4_11_0_, securedcus0_.address as address5_11_0_, securedcus0_.age as age6_11_0_, securedcus0_.name as name7_11_0_, securedcus0_.phoneNumber as phoneNum8_11_0_ from SecuredCustomer securedcus0_ where securedcus0_.loginId=?

And this SQL statement is working and returning the correct value.

when i am step by step debugging it is returning the data from the Database. but while running the same code in eclipse/tomcat, it is returning null object even when the object is available in the Table of the DB. i am testing the webapp on my localhost running Ubuntu...
Please help me out.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved... created a class

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response; 
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class MoxyThrowable implements javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(500).build();
    }
}
```

and viewed the detailed error. Then change some of the relevant fetchtype as EAGER. it sorted out the issue...